# No incrementa el id del modelo en Laravel, siempre me da 0?

Tags: mysql, laravel

estoy modificando una aplicación en Laravel 5.1 y el auto-incremento de la base de datos no funciona, ya que siempre se queda en el valor 0, muestra todos los campos con el id=0..muestro la migración que hice y la base de datos en phpmyadmin, a ver si alguien puede echar ayudar..gracias de antemano

**migración**

```
 Schema::create('refunds', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('contract_id')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('date_start');
        $table->text('notes');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('contract_id')->references('id')->on('contracts')->onDelete('cascade');    
    });
```

**phpmyadmin**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te falta declarar ID como primary key, si te fijas en las tablas del phpmyadmin no te deja eliminar ni editar un registro, esto sucede cuando la tabla no tiene la PK agregada

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar.. pero entiendo que en la migración declaro como clave primaria {$table->increments(ìd')}..lo he hecho con otros modelos y no he tenido este problema.

Comment: eso es lo extraño porque debería de declararla como primary key y no lo esta haciendo, si no para solucionar temporalmente $table->primary('id'); seguido del increments

Comment: Gracias nuevamente, probé a crear una nueva migración como dices, y si se hace el cambio en la base de datos de la clave primaria, pero sigue sin incrementar el valor, sigue dando 0 , con lo que al crear la segunda me da un error pq se repite la clave primaria en 0..

Comment: Revisa en Php myadmin la estructura de la tabla y verifica que la columna tenga el valor en autoincrement para salir de dudas

Comment: En la estructura de la tabla en phpmyadmin no se cambiaba el auto-incremento, solo la clave primaria.. como solución provisional elimine la columna id y timestamps con:  $table->dropcolumn('id'); $table->dropTimestamps() y y las volví a crear nuevamente.. y me esta funcionando..muchas gracias por tu tiempo.